# Reading JSON with Python Dicts

Tags: python, json, wordpress, dictionary

I have no idea if this is possible, I want to know if it's possible to use Python dicts to read JSON, I have crawled the web for answers, but I don't think anyone has had the same idea, or it's just not possible. It may be a confusing question, But, here it goes!

I have a Python Dict as;

```
 dict1 = {"3.8.1":"data[0]['3.8.1']","3.8":"data[1]['3.8']"}
```

As you can see, It'd get the json request string from the first dict with the found wordpress version number

```
dict1["3.8.1"]
```

would return the required next section to read from the loaded JSON file

I didn't "think" it was possible, but I thought I'd ask. As you can see in the above dict, It contains a way I could possibly request from the loaded JSON.

Anyway, any input, or other ways I could do it would be great, Thanks.

Comment: `"data[0]['3.8.1']"` isn't json. It's a string. I'm not sure what you are asking and your example isn't very clear.

Comment: Do you mean: parse a JSON document (such as `{ "data": [ { "3.8.1": "foo" } ], [ { "3.8": "bar" } ] }`, then access its elements based on contents of a string such as `"data[0]['3.8.1']"` to get at `"foo"`? That's the only way I can interpret your question at all; and if so, it smells of an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, I would use the second example to read from the dictionary, it'd return the required string to read from the json.

Comment: Yes, to parse the JSON document, with using the returned string from the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `exec()`?

```
exec("myvar = " + dict1["3.8.1"])
```